# Format for data & key exchange/storage

Tags: rsa, aes, pgp

Is there a standard format for storing/exchanging encrypted data along with the key needed to decrypt it (data is encrypted with a single use symmetric key and the symmetric key itself is encrypted with asymmetric key for the receiver)?

We are trying to build an interoperable protocol to exchange large messages between two parties that may not agree on much else besides using asymmetric keys. The best way seems to be using a symmetric single use key to encrypt the data and then encrypt it with the asymmetric key and pass along the whole thing as a package (e.g. RSA wrapped AES). So is there any widely used standard for sharing the encrypted text along with its key, preferably along with some information about the symmetric algorithm used.

The only work that I found in that direction is OpenPGP which is somewhat too implementation specific. I was wondering if there is anything else that has more metadata along with it to describe the algorithms and the keys.

Comment: Probably the most used protocol is CMS enveloped data. It is used for instance in S/MIME.

Comment: There's also NaCl / TweetNaCl / LibSodium's crypto_box* functions. Easy to use (especially libsodium's crypto_box_easy and crypto_box_seal), multiple implementations, etc, but no metadata on what ciphers are used since they're fixed to XSalsa20-Poly1305 with X25519.

Comment: There's also [XMLenc](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core1/) which was fairly big a few years ago (see: SOAP) but has faded, and [JWE](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7516) which is big now but may also be replaced by something else if fads change again.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I did look into XMLenc but I didn't think of JWT. I'll check it out.

Comment: @ГеоргиКременлиев Please never ask the same question at two places. This is called cross-posting and is considered very bad practice. I can only vote to close here, I'm only mod at the crypto site.